# Ads similar to Duolingo pop up ads in Android Studio - Java

Tags: java, android-studio, admob

I am wanting my pop up ads to have a similar style to the [Duolingo pop up ads](https://i.stack.imgur.com/THePh.png). But I am not sure how to do it and can't seem to find any resources on this.

Would this be a separate activity with a smart banner? Or is there a way to customise ad mobs interstitial ads?

I haven't found any resources so far and thinking if I use smart banners in a seperate activity it would be complicated to handle as I will also be working with fragments and passing data between the 2 already existing activities / fragments. Also concerned smart banners will have a much lower ECPM than interstitial.

Comment: It need a screen shot from what he want to make

Comment: @SaeedDarvish I have attached a screenshot hyperlink when you click on the 'Duolingo pop up ads' on my question

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't pay attention to the link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a full-screen dialog fragment. [This post](https://medium.com/alexander-schaefer/implementing-the-new-material-design-full-screen-dialog-for-android-e9dcc712cb38) completely explains the introduction. For the central box, use MaterialCardView and MaterialButton, or another container with a custom background.